# Copy numeric key for array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => '157a',
            [name] => '***',
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => '158a',
            [name] => '***',
        )
```

Need to copy the numeric keys (0, 1) for the array values ('157a', '158a'):

```
Array
(
    [157a] => Array
           (
               [id] => '157a',
               [name] => '***',
           )

    [158a] => etc
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking to create the 2nd array from the 1st array?

Comment: Rather than trying to modify the existing array, I just created a new array in the required format... Nice and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if its the efficient way, but i would do something like this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($array as $v)
{
   $newArray[$v['id']] = $v;
}
```

Comment: So it's basically just a matter of creating a new array, rather than editing the key name in an existing array?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `null` as the second parameter to `array_column()` to get the entire sub-array and pass `id` as the third to index the array by the values of that column:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for that:

```
array_column($input, $item, 'id');
```

Or you can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to do that in a functional programming way.

```
$changedArray = array_reduce($input, function ($result, $item) {
    $result[$item['id']] = $item;
    return $result;
}, array());
var_dump($changedArray);
```